# NAV RecordIDs in SQL - decoding date from hex string

Tags: hex, reverse-engineering, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to reverse engineer the Record IDs for a table, and have hit a stumbling block when I get to a date field as part of a record ID:

The recordID for one of my test records is:

`0x027D89000089FF4150303130353539000089FF4D43564100002E537116000000`

Which decodes as follows:

`0x027D8900` is the table ID in little endian, resolves to `9010434` (my table id)

`0x0089` refers to the "code" data type

`0xFF` indicates that my key contains characters

`0x415030313035353900` is my first primary key and resolves correctly to `AP010559` using a simple cast to varchar

the next section is the same for the second primary key and all resolves correctly using `cast`

However I am having trouble with the `002E537116000000`, this refers to a date and breaks down like this.

`0x002E` - "date" data type

`0x53711600` - the date, should resolve to 2013-06-17 but I can't work out how, note the last byte is just a termination

`0x0000` - 2 null bytes

Relevant links:

NAV data types: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nav/archive/2010/09/03/table-data-type-values-used-in-record-links.aspx

Structure of RecordID: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_dynamics_nav_sustained_engineering/archive/2009/08/06/how-do-record-links-encode-their-data-in-sql-server.aspx

Thanks in advance for any guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding a date field is indeed tricky.

It is actually a number of days since the earliest supported date (03-01-01), but multiplied by 2 (because even numbers correspond to normal dates, and odd - to closing dates), and with a small shift for special values.

Here is how it is calculated (example in PowerShell):

```
$days = [Convert]::ToInt32("167153", 16)
$datetime = new-object System.DateTime(((($days - 737) / 2) + 2) * [TimeSpan]::TicksPerDay)
Write-Host $datetime
```

Date type in NAV is stored as Int32, so the last byte is not a terminal, but the first byte of Int32 value in little endian. But, since the maximum possible date value is C31-12-9999 which corresponds to 0x92766F00, this byte is always 0 in date values.

737 is the minimum supported date (03-01-0001). Below this range are Undefined date (0D), and some other special constants like Minimum Date, Minimum Closing Date.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, just one query, in your answer you get the value of days by converting "167153" to Int32, where are you getting 167153 from?

Comment: I took it from you question.
The value you want to convert is 0x53711600. It is Int32 in little endian notation, so it should be reverted before processing.

Comment: Btw, if you read the RecordID into a byte array, you can use BitConverter:

[Byte[]]$byteArray = @(0x53,0x71,0x16,0x00)
$days = [Convert]::ToInt32([BitConverter]::ToInt32($byteArray), 16)
$datetime = new-object System.DateTime(((($days - 737) / 2) + 2) * [TimeSpan]::TicksPerDay)
Write-Host $datetime

Comment: What are Minimum Date and Minimum Closing Date? I've never heard of those. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of the solution provided by Alexander Drogin using SQL

Decoding a date:

```
DATEADD(Day, (convert(int, CAST(REVERSE(0xB5721600) as varbinary))-737)/2, CAST('0001-01-03' as date)) AS [DecodedDate]
```

Encoding a date:

```
CAST(REVERSE(CAST((DATEDIFF(Day, cast('0001-01-03' as date), cast('2013-12-11' as date))*2)+737 as varbinary)) as varbinary) AS [EncodedDate]
```

Tested and working with NAV 2009